# Strange usage of "collide"?

Tags: meaning

I was reading the paper today about a skier

> ...losing control on an icy ski slope and **colliding** with a tree.

This seems to be rather a strange usage of *collide*; the word seems to me to carry the implication that the things that *collide* are both active agents, and the tree cannot by any stretch of the imagination be held responsible for this accident. This definition [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/collide) seems to support that idea:-

> to strike one another or one against the other with a forceful impact;
> come into violent contact; crash: The two cars *collided* with an
> ear-splitting crash.

Is that so, or can stationary or even immobile objects *collide* with things?

Comment: Have you never been attacked by a lamp-post, taking mean advantage of your distraction/inebriation?

Comment: The skier collided with the tree. The skier was moving; the tree did not collide with the skier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

‘Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage’ has the answer (my emphasis):

> By far the greatest number of our citations for *collide* are
>   figurative, in which ideologies, politicians, nations, searing
>   glances, and the like collide. In these uses relative motion is not a
>   consideration. We thus suspect that you will seldom have to worry
>   about this matter. If you do, you may be assured that *collide* is
>   standard, **even when only one body is in motion**.

Comment: But since RHK Webster's also has the answer ( col•lide ... v.i. 1. to strike one another or one against the other with a forceful impact; crash. ... (Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary) surely this is General Reference.

Comment: Perhaps, but there does seem to have been some disagreement about it, at least in the past.